# Custom admin menu items

Tags: customization, admin-menu

I'm very new to Wordpress, familiar with CMS though.
I am taking over someone else's wordpress website, by comparing with other wordpress, I found this one has some admin menus that the other doesn't have, as the picture below shows
[image]

Are these coming from some plugin? I can't find a plugin in this site that looks like it is related to these menus. Is coding needed to add these custom menu items?

Comment: "Are these coming from some plugin?" - maybe; try deactivating all active plugins and see if those menus remained there - or deactivate just certain plugins and see there are any of the menus that are now gone. If not, then the menus probably added by the active theme - either by using functions like [`add_menu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/) or for custom post types (CPTs), WordPress by default will add the admin menu for managing the CPT posts.

Comment: Thanks I found the code already